# SaaS Sign Up Form Best Practices

Tags: wordpress, registration, mean-stack, multi-tenant, saas

I'm just looking for some best practices around how Registration/Sign-up forms are created for mulit-tenant SaaS applications.

Examples:
sendgrid.com/pricing -> Click on a plan and a modal pops up with a sign-up form
https://dashboard.stripe.com/register -> Sign up page for Stripe (looks like they do it on the actual application page, not the marketing page).

Basically I'm building a multi-tenant (single database, single server) web saas application using the MEAN stack. The application resides on a server and each tenant accesses their instance via subdomain. For example at:

```
tenant.mydomain.com
```

However we have a marketing site (the one where we sell people on our product and want them to sign-up for the app :)):

```
www.mydomain.com
```

Basically I'm trying to figure out how best to build the registration form that's on www.mydomain.com so that it integrates several pieces.

For example, should I write the marketing site in Wordpress and then write a plugin that makes a call to our API (hosted on app.mydomain.com/api/...) ?

OR for another example, should I do what Stripe does and re-direct to my application page and handle registrations there? How would this work for multiple tenants using subdomains?

Any resources or recommendations would be very helpful.

Thanks in advance everyone!

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the following should work fine

1. create a wordpress plugin that can make api calls to the application and get back the data and fill in the UI
2. Create a api key for the website `mydomain.com` that can be used to get the data by authenticating itself as the website, for security reasons
3. Just get the details like price, plan details from API and show in the website. Similarly, once the form is posted, post the data to the Api which will handle creating the registration as a tenant, approving the same, sending welcome email to the customer and notification to the admin about the registration etc..
4. The backend business logic can alone be with the app, secured well by an Api Key. However, the presentation can be anywhere, in your case it can be a wordpress App.